# Displaying Bit Values to Checklist Box by DataGridView CellClick Event

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, datagridview, checklistbox

I'm currently working on a database system using VB.NET and SQL Server, everything's working ok except my CheckListBox and the other objects the came after it.

I created an Event where whenever I click on a cell inside my DataGridView, the bit (datatype) data in it will be displayed on my CheckListBox and change values depending on the cell I click.

The problem is: I click once and the checkboxes get checked according to the cell I clicked, but once I click on another cell with different bit values in it, the checkboxes doesn't change, then the rest of the code after it doesn't work.

Here's  a sample of the code I used:

```
 Private Sub dgvMain_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvMain.CellClick
 Try

     /*These codes work....*/

            dtpReg.Text = dgvMain.Item(1, e.RowIndex).Value
            txtFirstName.Text = dgvMain.Item(2, e.RowIndex).Value
            txtMiddleName.Text = dgvMain.Item(3, e.RowIndex).Value
            txtLastName.Text = dgvMain.Item(4, e.RowIndex).Value
            If dgvMain.Item(5, e.RowIndex).Value = True Then
                optMale.Checked = True
            Else
                optFemale.Checked = True
            End If
            dtpBirthdate.Text = dgvMain.Item(6, e.RowIndex).Value
            cboCivilStatus.Text = dgvMain.Item(8, e.RowIndex).Value
            dtpResidency.Text = dgvMain.Item(9, e.RowIndex).Value
            txtSt.Text = dgvMain.Item(10, e.RowIndex).Value
            cboBrgy.Text = dgvMain.Item(11, e.RowIndex).Value
            cboEducation.Text = dgvMain.Item(12, e.RowIndex).Value
            chkStudy.Checked = dgvMain.Item(13, e.RowIndex).Value
            chkTB.Checked = dgvMain.Item(14, e.RowIndex).Value
            chkMalnourished.Checked = dgvMain.Item(15, e.RowIndex).Value
            chkIllDisabled.Checked = dgvMain.Item(16, e.RowIndex).Value
            chkSoloParent.Checked = dgvMain.Item(17, e.RowIndex).Value
            chkActive.Checked = dgvMain.Item(19, e.RowIndex).Value
            If dgvMain.Item(20, e.RowIndex).Value = "Public center/hospital" Then
                optPublic.Checked = True
            ElseIf dgvMain.Item(20, e.RowIndex).Value = "Private center/hospital" Then
                optPrivate.Checked = True
            ElseIf dgvMain.Item(20, e.RowIndex).Value = "Non-professional" Then
                optNonProf.Checked = True
            End If
            txtTelephone.Text = dgvMain.Item(21, e.RowIndex).Value
            txtMobile.Text = dgvMain.Item(22, e.RowIndex).Value
            txtEmail.Text = dgvMain.Item(23, e.RowIndex).Value

  /*Unemployed ----> This is where the CheckListBox problem occurs*/

            If dgvMain.Item(24, e.RowIndex).Value = True Then

                clbUnemployed.SetItemCheckState(0, CheckState.Checked)
            Else
                clbUnemployed.SetItemCheckState(0, CheckState.Unchecked)
            End If
            If dgvMain.Item(25, e.RowIndex).Value = True Then
                clbUnemployed.SetItemCheckState(1, CheckState.Checked)
            Else
                clbUnemployed.SetItemCheckState(1, CheckState.Unchecked)
            End If
            If dgvMain.Item(26, e.RowIndex).Value = True Then
                clbUnemployed.SetItemCheckState(2, CheckState.Checked)
            Else
                clbUnemployed.SetItemCheckState(2, CheckState.Unchecked)
            End If
            If dgvMain.Item(27, e.RowIndex).Value = True Then
                clbUnemployed.SetItemCheckState(3, CheckState.Checked)
            Else
                clbUnemployed.SetItemCheckState(3, CheckState.Unchecked)
            End If
            If dgvMain.Item(28, e.RowIndex).Value = True Then
                clbUnemployed.SetItemCheckState(4, CheckState.Checked)
            Else
                clbUnemployed.SetItemCheckState(4, CheckState.Unchecked)
            End If
            If dgvMain.Item(29, e.RowIndex).Value = True Then
                clbUnemployed.SetItemCheckState(5, CheckState.Checked)
            Else
                clbUnemployed.SetItemCheckState(5, CheckState.Unchecked)
            End If
            If dgvMain.Item(30, e.RowIndex).Value = True Then
                clbUnemployed.SetItemCheckState(6, CheckState.Checked)
            Else
                clbUnemployed.SetItemCheckState(6, CheckState.Unchecked)
            End If
            If dgvMain.Item(31, e.RowIndex).Value = True Then
                clbUnemployed.SetItemCheckState(7, CheckState.Checked)
            Else
                clbUnemployed.SetItemCheckState(7, CheckState.Unchecked)
            End If
            If dgvMain.Item(32, e.RowIndex).Value = True Then
                clbUnemployed.SetItemCheckState(8, CheckState.Checked)
            Else
                clbUnemployed.SetItemCheckState(8, CheckState.Unchecked)
            End If
            If dgvMain.Item(33, e.RowIndex).Value = True Then
                clbUnemployed.SetItemCheckState(9, CheckState.Checked)
            Else
                clbUnemployed.SetItemCheckState(9, CheckState.Unchecked)
            End If
            If dgvMain.Item(34, e.RowIndex).Value = True Then
                clbUnemployed.SetItemCheckState(10, CheckState.Checked)
            Else
                clbUnemployed.SetItemCheckState(10, CheckState.Unchecked)
            End If
            If dgvMain.Item(35, e.RowIndex).Value = True Then
                clbUnemployed.SetItemCheckState(11, CheckState.Checked)
            Else
                clbUnemployed.SetItemCheckState(11, CheckState.Unchecked)
            End If
            If dgvMain.Item(36, e.RowIndex).Value = True Then
                clbUnemployed.SetItemCheckState(12, CheckState.Checked)
            Else
                clbUnemployed.SetItemCheckState(12, CheckState.Unchecked)
            End If

/*Employment ---> the code after this doesn't work. Text doesn't display. Not one RadioButton checked. No picture on the picturebox. Why?*/

            cboIndustry.Text = dgvMain.Item(37, e.RowIndex).Value
            txtSalary.Text = dgvMain.Item(38, e.RowIndex).Value
            cboJobStatus.Text = dgvMain.Item(39, e.RowIndex).Value
            If dgvMain.Item(40, e.RowIndex).Value = True Then
                optGyes.Checked = True
            Else
                optGno.Checked = True
            End If
            txtBrgySubd.Text = dgvMain.Item(41, e.RowIndex).Value
            txtCityMunicipality.Text = dgvMain.Item(42, e.RowIndex).Value
            txtProvince.Text = dgvMain.Item(43, e.RowIndex).Value
         Dim ms As New MemoryStream(changephoto(CInt(dgvMain.SelectedCells(0).Value)))
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)

 Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: Your throwing an exception. Can you set a breakpoint and step through...

Comment: If i recall as well to check a cells value it should be: dgvMain.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(yourcolumn).Value

Comment: Thanks!!! Actually I've never tried that 'cause I'm still starting out as a new programmer and learn only from examples. I'll see if I can find what's wrong and post a solution. I really do appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment above, try checking for your values as shown below; you may want to cast those cells as `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` as well. Also your probably throwing an exception in your code, please set a breakpoint and step through to see if one if thrown, if so please post that exception so I can better assist you.

```
 If CType(dgvMain.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("your column"), DataGridViewCheckBoxCell).Value Then
   'Do your work if it's true
 Else
   'Do something else...
 End If
```

Comment: I tried your code above but it gives me this error:

`InvalidCastException was unhandled` 

`Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Boolean' is not valid`

Answer (score 0):

I added ToString after Value and it did the trick.

```
If dgvMain.Item(35, e.RowIndex).Value.ToString = "True" Then
clbUnemployed.SetItemCheckState(0, CheckState.Checked)
Else
clbUnemployed.SetItemCheckState(0, CheckState.Unchecked)
End If
```

...but now I'm having trouble displaying the photo on PictureBox1. The problem seems to be originating in here (you can also see the code above):

```
Dim ms As New MemoryStream(changephoto(CInt(dgvMain.SelectedCells(0).Value)))
PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
```

I used this function to do it:

```
Function changephoto(ByVal photo As Integer) As Byte()
        sqlCon.Open()
        With sqlComm
            .Connection = sqlCon
            .CommandText = "SELECT Photo FROM Picture WHERE PersonId =" & dgvMain.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value
        End With
        Dim myphoto() As Byte = CType(sqlComm.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())
        sqlCon.Close()
        Return myphoto
    End Function
```

Error says: Conversion from type 'datatype(this depends on the cell I click)' to type 'Integer' is not valid.